# Adding custom key to aframe-super-keyboard

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to add an @ key to the super-keyboard

I generated this code from the example:
{"key":"@", "x":0.109, "y":0.836, "w":0.162, "h":0.163}

And added the symbol to the image

And I assume I add it this way:

```
aframe.registerComponent('show-keyboard', {
    dependencies: ['super-keyboard'],
    init: function(){
      var model = { 
        wrapCount: 30, inputOffsetY: 0.008, inputOffsetX: 0.08, img: 'my-keyboard.png',
        layout: [...all keys from basic..,{"key":"@", "x":0.109, "y":0.836, "w":0.162, "h":0.163}]
      }
      this.el.components['super-keyboard'].addCustomModel('show', model)
    }
  });
```

Keyboard attributes:

```
        'showhow-keyboard': {},
        'super-keyboard' : {  
            model: 'show',
            imagePath: '/assets/images/',
        },
```

I get no keyboard.

If I remove the model attribute the keyboard shows..

Answer (score 0):

Changed the order I added the components and its working.